# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.platformmisc.NativePlatformMisc.nativeGetEnvironmentVariable

Tags: tfs, sdk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am getting the below error while connecting to tfs.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.platformmisc.NativePlatformMisc.nativeGetEnvironmentVariable

code : 
public class ConnectionToVisualStudio
{

```
public static  TFSTeamProjectCollection connectToTFS()
{
    System.setProperty("com.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory", "C:\\Users\\userName\\native");
    TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = null;
    Credentials credentials;

    credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username","password");
    tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(URIUtils.newURI("https://xyz.visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject"), credentials);
    return tpc;
}
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc;

    tpc = ConnectionToVisualStudio.connectToTFS();
    Project project = tpc.getWorkItemClient().getProjects().get("MyFirstProject");
    // Find the work item type matching the specified name.
    WorkItemType bugWorkItemType = project.getWorkItemTypes().get("Bug");

    // Create a new work item of the specified type.
    WorkItem newWorkItem = project.getWorkItemClient().newWorkItem(bugWorkItemType);

    // Set the title on the work item.
    newWorkItem.setTitle("Example Work Item");

    // Add a comment as part of the change
    newWorkItem.getFields().getField(CoreFieldReferenceNames.HISTORY).setValue(
        "<p>Created automatically by a sample</p>");

    // Save the new work item to the server.
    newWorkItem.save();

    System.out.println("Work item " + newWorkItem.getID() + " successfully created");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Seems you didn't set `com.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory` as system property correctly.

Just try setting it as below:

```
System.setProperty("com.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory", "C:\Users\userName\native");
```

Or set it in command prompt:

```
java.exe -D"com.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory=C:\Users\Username\YourApplication\native"
```

Reference this article: [Getting going with the TFS Java API](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2013/05/04/Getting-going-with-the-TFS-Java-API)

Comment: @gurchet singh Have you resolved the issue by above solution? any update?